# No OpenGL 3 headers in Arch Linux

Tags: c++, opengl-3, archlinux

I’m trying to compile a very simple “Hello world” OpenGL 3.3 program using FreeGLUT. In all the tutorials I found, they include an header “gl3.h”. The problem is, I don’t have such header file.

```
$ ls -l /usr/include/GL/
total 2164
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8797 20 janv. 17:44 freeglut_ext.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    681 20 janv. 17:44 freeglut.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26181 20 janv. 17:44 freeglut_std.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 837247 27 janv. 12:55 glew.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 656589 21 mars  18:07 glext.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  84468 21 mars  18:07 gl.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128943 21 mars  18:07 gl_mangle.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17255 21 mars  18:07 glu.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3315 21 mars  18:07 glu_mangle.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    639 20 janv. 17:44 glut.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62741 27 janv. 12:55 glxew.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43887 21 mars  18:07 glxext.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17170 21 mars  18:07 glx.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4706  3 févr. 13:33 glxint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3463 21 mars  18:07 glx_mangle.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2086  3 févr. 13:33 glxmd.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  80979  3 févr. 13:33 glxproto.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11246  3 févr. 13:33 glxtokens.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 14 avril 14:03 internal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8497 21 mars  18:07 osmesa.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51274 21 mars  18:07 vms_x_fix.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  59403 27 janv. 12:55 wglew.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  41377 21 mars  18:07 wglext.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4468 21 mars  18:07 wmesa.h
```

In `/usr/include/` I only have `GL`, `GLES` and `GLES2`. There is no `GL3` as I found in some tutorials.

I’m running on Arch Linux x86_64 with a NVIDIA graphic card (`nvidia` closed-source driver).

Here is how I included OpenGL and FreeGLUT APIs in my program:

```
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

But the code doesn’t compile:

```
$ g++ -pipe -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I. -IHeaders -c Sources/Main.cpp -o Temp/Objects/Main.o 
Sources/Main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Sources/Main.cpp:107:59: error: ‘glVertexAttribPointer’ was not declared in this scope
Sources/Main.cpp:108:30: error: ‘glEnableVertexAttribArray’ was not declared in this scope
Sources/Main.cpp:114:35: error: ‘glUseProgram’ was not declared in this scope
Sources/Main.cpp:138:31: error: ‘glDisableVertexAttribArray’ was not declared in this scope
```

It seems I included the OpenGL 2 headers! But, again, I didn’t find any OpenGL 3 headers on my system, I looked at the Arch repository and AUR, unsuccessfully.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a GL3.h, the GL3.h just got rid of all deprecated features. So just include `gl.h` instead of `gl3.h`. Downloading and manually copyieng into `/usr/include/GL/` is not a real solution, it works yes, but what happens if the add to the `mesa` package the `gl3.h`? You're package manager will find conflicts. Better you add the `gl3.h` to your project or into your home directory and add it to the $PATh or use the -I flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you `grep` for  glVertexAttribPointer, glEnableVertexAttribArray, glUseProgram and glDisableVertexAttribArray, you will find that they are included in `glext.h` and `glew.h`. Try to include one of these headers and compile again.

Comment: If I only include `glew.h` the code compile but doesn’t link because I have to link the GLEW library, but actually, I don’t need GLEW so I’ll use the `gl3.h` directly. For `glext.h`, errors are the same.