# Where can I get GL3/gl3.h on Ubuntu or probably it is deprecated?

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

If I [build some open source library configured to use OpenGL 3 on Ubuntu](https://developernote.com/2017/08/building-osgearth-on-ubuntu-14-04/), its CMake generates a header file containing

```c
#include <GL3/gl3.h>
```

but GL3/gl3.h does not exist on my system. If I replace GL3/gl3.h with GL/gl.h, the library compiles and works fine. I [reported this situation to the library owners](https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/issues/305), but they said that I should have this GL3/gl3.h. Also there is an [answer telling that GL3/gl3.h is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400072/no-opengl-3-headers-in-arch-linux). Where can I get GL3/gl3.h? And isn't it deprecated?

Comment: You didn't read that answer you linked correctly. It doesn't say that `gl3.h` were deprecated. It says that `gl3.h` is a stripped down version of `gl.h` from which all the deprecated stuff (things that are no longer supported by OpenGL-3 and onward) had been removed from.

Comment: good! any ideas on where can I get this gl3.h ?

Comment: gl3.h is only for OpenGL-ES, not OpenGL desktop.

Comment: While it may be true that default Ubuntu has GLES3/gl3.h, that doesn't meant that gl3 is only for GLES. Tons of tutorials all reference it as GL3/gl3.h, which is the desktop path, not the ES path.